# Remove Current Row without ID (PHP, MYSQL, HTML)

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am working on a HTML website. I am using a MySQL Database and PHP.

The concept so far is fairly simple:

1. The user can add some text onto the site by clicking on an add button - the user gets directed to a page with a dialogue box
2. When he clicks submit, that text is in the data base.
3. The PHP code knows: while the data base has entries -> echo the text onto the HTML website (I added a while loop)

Now my next step is to let the user delete the text. I added a trash can glyphicon onto the HTML site. When the user clicks it, I would like for the current row in the table to be removed. Unfortunately nothing happens!

Here's the code:

```
<?php
    $query = " SELECT * FROM Thesis";
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

    ?>


<div class="box green-box">

    <p><div class="center-box-content">

    <!--echo the title -->
        <?php echo $row["title"]; ?>

        <br> 

   <!--echo the description -->
       <?php echo $row["description"]; ?>
    </p>

    <div class="lower-right-box-content">

        <a href="adminview.php">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash glyphicon-trash" role="button">
            <?php
            $delquery = " DELETE * FROM Thesis";
            mysqli_query($conn, $delquery);

            ?>
            </span>
        </a>

    </div>

</div>
</div>
<?php };
?>
```

What am I doing wrong? I know that the main mistake must lie somewhere 
in $delquery. But I am lost.
I also know that it would be better to have an ID for each row. But I would like to avoid it, because since we are in a while loop, there must be a way to just delete the current row that the while loop is in, right? That would be my preferred solution.

Lastly, I am very new to programming and not the most elegant programmer yet, please be kind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want a simple ID for your thesis table, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Thesis` (
  `thesis_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`thesis_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I would separate out the PHP from the display code, putting the PHP code at the top of your file.  For security and better code, I would use bind variables with PDO (instead of mysqli).  But sticking with your original code, I would rewrite it like this:

```
<?php

// Establish the connection
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

// Delete a specific element
if (isset($_GET['delete_id']) && $_GET['delete_id'] > 0) {
    $query = "DELETE FROM Thesis WHERE thesis_id = " . $_GET['delete_id'];
    mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}

// Gather all the rows
$query = "SELECT * FROM Thesis";
$count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
$rows  = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $rows[] = $row;
}

?>

<?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>

<div class="box green-box">

    <p><div class="center-box-content">

    <!--echo the title -->
    <?= $row["title"] ?>


    <br> 

    <!--echo the description -->
    <?= $row["description"] ?>

    </p>

    <div class="lower-right-box-content">

        <a href="adminview.php?delete=<?= $row['thesis_id'] ?>">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash glyphicon-trash" role="button"></span>
        </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The `foreach` call above is a common PHP shortcut, and the `<?=` tag will echo back something without having to call `echo`.  The deletion of element using a GET call is not recommended, but for simplicity I'm keeping it in place.

Comment: Hi @Charlie, thank you! I did add a simple id now, because I realized there is no way around it, and it makes things much simpler. My questions is: where do I have to place the code that deletes the selected row in order for the row to be deleted upon clicking of the trash glyphicon?

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING: BE CAREFUL OF SQL INJECTIONS!!**

Now, back to the problem.
First of all, your delete SQL code is run every time a row is inserted, so you will never have rows. First step is to delete

```
        <?php
        $delquery = " DELETE * FROM Thesis";
        mysqli_query($conn, $delquery);

        ?>
```

Next, you want that certain row to be deleted if the user clicks the trash icon. To do this, you can pass the row ID to a PHP page via `<a>` or `$.ajax`, then delete it from that PHP page. However, **BE CAREFUL OF SQL INJECTIONS**

So you would need on your main page:

```
<a href="deleteRow.php?id=<? echo $row['id'] ?>">[delete icon]</a>
```

And on your `deleteRow.php`:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
//anti-injection code
mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM Thesis WHERE id='$id'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <a href="adminview.php">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash glyphicon-trash" role="button">
        <?php
        $delquery = " DELETE * FROM Thesis";
        mysqli_query($conn, $delquery);

        ?>
        </span>
   </a>
```

In above code you deleting all the rows. which is wrong. what you should do is:

```
    <a href="adminview.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"];?>">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash glyphicon-trash" role="button"></span>
    </a>
```

in adminview.php

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {            
     $delquery = " DELETE FROM Thesis WHERE id= '".$_REQUEST['id']."' ";
     mysqli_query($conn, $delquery);            
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ahmed, thank you for your response! I have two questions: 1.: The code I wrote already is written in adminview.php. I want the page to reload with the text removed once the user clicks the delete button. Do I write both of your suggestions into the same file (adminview.php) then, or write a new file?
2.: My rows don't have an ID, do you think its impossible without adding an ID column into my table ?

Comment: Yes you can use same page to delete each record. Do you have any primary key in that table ?

Comment: I just Added an additional column named "id" that auto increments for every entry in the table. Then I tried your code but for some reason, it still does nothing. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: I Just edited my answer hence error on delete query. check it and update it